# $scope.$on causes Angular to silently fail

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The problem seems to be in a factory called `EventFactory`. Two statements in the factory are the problem. They are:

```
        $scope.$on('event:updateStuff', function (event, data) {
            myObj = data;
        });

        $scope.$on('event:updateOtherStuff', function (event, data) {
            myArray.push(data);
        });
```

These statements were working fine before, now I can't get the page to render unless I comment out the entire `$scope.$on`. I haven't made any code changes since I last ran the application successfully so this behavior is quite unexpected. No error message appears on the console.

Restoring the `$scope.$on` while commenting out the inner statements does not resolve the issue. I've commented them out and the page still fails to render.

This causes the page to fail:

```
        $scope.$on('event:updateStuff', function (event, data) {
            myObj = data;
        });

        $scope.$on('event:updateOtherStuff', function (event, data) {
            myArray.push(data);
        });
```

This also causes the page to fail:

```
        $scope.$on('event:updateStuff', function (event, data) {
            /*myObj = data;*/
        });

        $scope.$on('event:updateOtherStuff', function (event, data) {
            /*myArray.push(data);*/
        });
```

Only with the entire `$scope.$on` commented out does the page load:

```
        //$scope.$on('event:updateStuff', function (event, data) {
            //myObj = data;
        //});

        //$scope.$on('event:updateOtherStuff', function (event, data) {
            //myArray.push(data);
        //});
```

Comment: @A.J I've edited for clarity. I'm saying that it's not the function that gets called by `$scope.$on` that causes the problem, merely the presence of `$scope.$on` causes the page to fail to load.

Comment: what do you get if you `console.log($scope, $scope.$on)`?

Comment: Can you post the entire controller code?

Comment: Can you show what you are injecting for the `$scope` dependency for your service? Is it `$rootScope`? Or does `$scope` come from elsewhere? It's not super common to have scopes in factories/services.

Comment: @GregL That was it. Not sure how I lost the `root` prefix. If you make it an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A service doesn't usually have access to a `$scope` like a controller does. At best, it can either get one passed to it as a parameter to its methods, or it can inject the `$rootScope` service.

The simplest is probably just to make sure you are injecting and referring to `$rootScope` in your factory/service, instead of `$scope`.